# Does MT 5:22 contradict other passages regarding Anger & Fool?

Tags: matthew, contradiction

Is calling someone a fool subject to the hell fire & being angry a sin – when Jesus was angry & called others a Fool.

All passages from ***English Standard Version***

But I say to you that ***everyone who is angry*** with his brother will be liable to judgment; whoever insults his brother will be liable to the council; and whoever says, ***‘You fool!’*** will be liable to the ***hell of fire.***

***Call someone a Fool***

MT 7:26 But anyone who hears my teaching and doesn’t obey it is ***foolish,*** like a person who builds a house on sand.

(Note: translation the oldest Greek manuscripts use the ***same Greek word translated “fool” in MT 5:22*** and “like a foolish man” in MT 7:26.)

MT 23:17-19 Blind ***fools!*** Which is more important—the gold or the Temple that makes the gold sacred?

***MT 25:2, 3, 8***

2 Five of them were ***foolish,*** and five were wise.
3 The five who were ***foolish*** didn’t take enough olive oil for their lamps,
8 Then the five ***foolish*** ones asked the others, ‘Please give us some of your oil because our lamps are going out.’

(Note: translation - this is the same Greek word translated “fool” in MT 5:22 and MT 23:17-19.)

Galatians 3:1 Oh, ***foolish*** Galatians! Who has cast an evil spell on you? For the meaning of Jesus Christ’s death was made as clear to you as if you had seen a picture of his death on the cross.

1CO 4:10 Our dedication to Christ makes us look like ***fools,*** but you claim to be so wise in Christ! We are weak, but you are so powerful! You are honored, but we are ridiculed.

(Note: Again, this is the same Greek word translated “fool” in MT 5:22 and MT 23:17-19.)

***Anger / curse***

EP 4:26 Be ***angry*** and do not sin; do not let the sun go down on your anger,

[Anger is not necessarily a sin.]

MT 21:19 and he noticed a fig tree beside the road. He went over to see if there were any figs, but there were only leaves. Then he said to it, “May you never bear fruit again!” And immediately the fig tree withered up.

[Jesus curses a fig tree & Mark 11-14]

MK 3:5 He looked around at them ***angrily*** and was deeply saddened by their hard hearts. Then he said to the man, “Hold out your hand.” So the man held out his hand, and it was restored!

Please provide passages from the bible to support an answer

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/62985/did-jesus-assure-the-hellish-outcome-in-matthew-522

Comment: just search "fool angry" keyword

Answer (score 0):

The original Greek word translated "foolish" is μωρός from which our English word "moron" comes directly.  It is also preserved in our expression, "oxymoron" = (literally) sharp-blunt(stupid), ie, a contradiction.

The primary meaning of the word is not so much "foolish" as "stupid" as can be readily seen from its 12 occurrences in the NT: Matt 5:22, 7:26, 23:17, 25:2, 3, 8, 1 Cor 1:25, 27, 3:18, 4:10, 2 Tim 2:23, Titus 3:9.

The case of Matt 5:22 is a **special case** about which BDAG makes some helpful remarks:

> The meaning of μωρέ Matt 5:22 is disputed. Most scholars take it as
> the ancient Syrian versions did, to mean *you fool* [ ... as it is
> accented in Att.] = you fool! ... something also with the connotation
> of an obstinate godless person. From the time of HPaulus, Commentators
> (various ...) it has been held to be a transliteration of מוֹרֶ֔ה
> rebel (Deut 21:18, 20) ...

If this latter, quite plausible theory is correct, then the apparent contradiction disappears.  Then, Matt 5:22 would be more helpfully translated:

> ... but whosoever shall say, "You rebel", shall be in danger of hell
> fire.

This theory is supported by the fact that "Raca" is also from the Hebrew as Ellicott observes:

> Raca.—As far as the dictionary sense of the word goes, it is the same
> as that of the “vain fellows” of Judges 9:4, Jdg_11:3; Proverbs 12:11;
> but all words of abuse depend for their full force on popular
> association, and raca, like words of kindred meaning among ourselves,
> was in common use as expressing not anger only but insolent contempt.
> The temper condemned is that in which anger has so far gained the
> mastery that we no longer recognise a “brother” in the man who has
> offended us, but look on him with malignant scorn.

Further, Ellicott also observes a similar thing for μωρέ -

> **Thou fool**.—The Greek word so rendered agrees accidentally in its consonants with the Hebrew word translated “rebel” (m’re) in Numbers
> 20:10, and hence it has been thought by some that we have here, as
> with raca, a common Hebrew term of opprobrium. ...

In all other places in the NT, the word simply means "stupid", or "moronic".

**APPENDIX - Deut 21:18-20**

I quote the text of Deut 21:18-20 for completeness highlighting the Hebrew word מוֹרֶ֔ה showing that the NT word μωρέ could well be a transliteration from the Hebrew.

If a man has a stubborn and **rebellious** son who does not obey his father and mother and does not listen to them when disciplined, his father and mother are to lay hold of him and bring him to the elders of his city, to the gate of his hometown, and say to the elders, “This son of ours is stubborn and **rebellious**; he does not obey us. He is a glutton and a drunkard.”

Comment: helpful information, albeit with assumptions.  Unfortunately, it does not solve the contradiction, 1) the same Greek word should be translated the same in all passages 2)  if you substitute all the passages with either stupid or rebel - then Jesus and Paul etc... are still liable to hell, because they have called someone stupid or a rebel.

Comment: @anothertheory - that is the point of the answer - it is a different word from the other instances and thus should be treated differently; that is unless you really are determined to create a contradiction.

Comment: noted - as point 1 above the same Greek word is used in the other passages - so you cant have it specially translated in Mt 5.22 and not the others as the 'special case' should apply to all passages with the identical word.  It is not a matter of creating a contradiction, the theory / possible assumptions in your 'A' appear to be just an attempt to get out of a problem.  But its the same word so should be treated the same in all the passages.

Comment: @anothertheory - I am surprised to hear you say that.  Greek like every language depends much on context.  "The nurse then wound the wound".  Are both words "wound" the same?  The reason Matt 5:22 should be treated differently is explained above.  But you are welcome to believe as you will and create contradictions.

Comment: the context may change the meaning / understanding of a sentence, but the word still remains the same 'wound'.  But you are welcome to believe as you will to satisfy your conscience.

Answer (score 0):

The word "fool" in Matthew 5:22, to my understanding, the original script is a Aramaic word, that KJV translate it as "Thou fool". Will it be possible that English translation not accurate to the right expression ?

When Jesus taught his disciples the actual meaning of "You shall not murder", He quote these examples in Matthew 5:22 (NIV) that begins with ***"But I tell you that anyone who is angry with a brother or sister ............"***. Applying to nowadays, the subject are Christians who know each other. It described one Christian is in hatred of his/her fellow Christian, did or said something with malice aforethought, will be subjected to serious punishment, equivalent to murder.

John had his episode 1 John 3:15 (NIV) quote ***" Anyone who hates a brother or sister is a murderer, and you know that no murderer has eternal life residing in him"***, exactly express the same meaning as in Matthew 5:22.

Other occasions that Jesus used the word "fool" or "foolish", were in his teaching, parables that were not specific to a named person, and not even to a fellow disciple.

Therefore anger would cause someone to avenge, did or said something with a "malice aforethought", it's consequence could be equivalent to "Murder".

Answer (score 0):

> “You have heard that the ancients were told, you shalt not commit
> murder…. But I say to you, whoever says, ‘You fool,’ shall be in
> danger of hell fire,”

“You shalt not commit murder” simply reflects a basic principle of the law as it applies in the extreme case. When he says, “but whosoever shall say, ‘You fool,’ shall be in danger of hell fire,” he is establishing the link between one’s attitude toward his brother and the extreme outcome of that attitude. You begin not to commit murder by not hatting your brother. You do this by loving your neighbor as yourself. You begin not hating your brother by not even so much as regarding him as a fool. The law “You shalt not commit murder” is simply the basic principle that extends well beyond the elemental act itself. What Jesus is showing us is HOW you do not commit murder. Calling one’s brother a fool demonstrates a contempt for one’s brother. Contempt leads to hatred and hatred leads to murder. Having contempt for your brother is a “danger” signal. “Whosoever shall say, ‘You fool,’ shall be in danger of hell fire.’” This person is in danger of acting on that contempt, perhaps even in the extreme act of murder.